# Set row number sequentially in matrix table in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-365

I have a SSRS report which consists of the matrix table. This matrix has a row Groups called ItemId1. I want to add line number to this matrix. when I add a expression RowNumber(nothing) the results is as follow :

[image]

when I add expression RowNumber("ItemId1"), the report is shown as follow:

[image]

I want just line number based on the row, I mean I expect line number 2 instead of 7 (or 8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use RowNumber as this looks at the dataset rather than what is displayed. What you actually need to do is get the number of unique `ItemID`'s on or before each group.

This is actually much simpler than it sounds !

You can use `RunningValue` to do exactly this.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ItemId.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

You will just need to change the dataset name to whatever your dataset is actually called.

Here's the output from a sample report I created. The first column shows a similar result to yours when RowNumnber is used. The second column uses the RunningValue method.

[image]

Comment: Thank you your answer helps me.

Comment: I should mention that the line number column must be inside the group.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

on Right hand side I have grouped by Category and Here is how I solved it

```
=RunningValue(Fields!category.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

In your case it shall be

```
=RunningValue(Fields!ItemId.Value,CountDistinct, "DataSet1")
```

Comment: No itemId1 is row group in matrix it is not a field

Comment: Yes and how does it change the answer?
you have grouped as row with field ItemId and using same field in runningValue function will give you desired result.

Comment: Ok now your edited answer is correct which is same as the answer that @Alan Schofield had been provided before you.

Comment: Yeah it was typo. Sure no worries alan was faster :)